# how to integrate fFacebook login with your website?

Tags: php, facebook, authentication

I made some research and i can't seem to completely understand how to integrate Facebook login with your website.

I'm trying to do this for an old fashioned PHP shop that, up till now, doesn't use any type of login, but only a session that allows users to browse across pages and add items to cart.

I read here, on Stack Overflow, that you need a table in your database to keep the user's email address and facebook_id. So after that I can hook up with other tables in my database in order to provide info and much more to each user?

Are there other ways to easily integrate your website with Facebook  and Google accounts? I read something about OpenID, but didn't really understand what's its use :)

So that's why I'm asking you to put me on track :). I'm really new with this and any advice, best practices etc. will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The idea behind Facebook login is simple: The user goes to the Facebook page, logs in there, Facebook worries about the details and eventually just gives you (your server) a thumbs up and an id, meaning *"we have positively confirmed the identity of this user, it's user 174264384"*. Your server is then free to do whatever it likes with this information. If you want to track a user across several visits then yes, you'll probably want to store that number in a database together with any additional information. The next time Facebook tells you user 174264384 has logged in, you can get any associated information back out of your database.

Hope that helps as a 30,000 feet overview. The details of how Facebook can securely authenticate a user and hand this information back to your server are best handled by the [PHP SDK](https://github.com/facebook/php-sdk). Read the [documentation](http://developer.facebook.com/) if you want to explore the details.

OpenID basically does the same thing, only the technical details differ and it's not specific to Facebook. Oauth is another very similar technology.

Comment: I have a question about gettin the old information about a user when he signs againg with facebook. I am using php to get the old information from my database. But what about security? If I use only the facebook id anyone can get the information with using only the facebook id.

Answer (score 9):

There is an official Facebook tutorial on how to do this with JS:

[Official Facebook Tutorial](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/login/getting-started/)

Answer (score 4):

I thought it will helpful to you, if you want to use javascript sdk for this please copy this code :

```
<DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>

<title>Facebook Login JavaScript Example</title>

<meta charset=”UTF-8″>

</head>

<body>

<script>

// This is called with the results from from FB.getLoginStatus().

function statusChangeCallback(response) {

console.log(‘statusChangeCallback’);

console.log(response);

// The response object is returned with a status field that lets the

// app know the current login status of the person.

// Full docs on the response object can be found in the documentation

// for FB.getLoginStatus().

if (response.status === ‘connected’) {

// Logged into your app and Facebook.

testAPI();

} else if (response.status === ‘not_authorized’) {

// The person is logged into Facebook, but not your app.

document.getElementById(‘status’).innerHTML = ‘Please log ‘ +

‘into this app.';

} else {

// The person is not logged into Facebook, so we’re not sure if

// they are logged into this app or not.

document.getElementById(‘status’).innerHTML = ‘Please log ‘ +

‘into Facebook.';

}

}
// This function is called when someone finishes with the Login

// Button. See the onlogin handler attached to it in the sample

// code below.

function checkLoginState() {

FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {

statusChangeCallback(response);

});

}
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {

FB.init({

appId : ‘{your-app-id}’,// plaste your app id

cookie : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access

// the session

xfbml : true, // parse social plugins on this page

version : ‘v2.1′ // use version 2.1

});

// These three cases are handled in the callback function.
FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {

statusChangeCallback(response);

});
};
// Load the SDK asynchronously

(function(d, s, id) {

var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];

if (d.getElementById(id)) return;

js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;

js.src = “//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js”;

fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);

}(document, ‘script’, ‘facebook-jssdk’));
// Here we run a very simple test of the Graph API after login is

// successful. See statusChangeCallback() for when this call is made.

function testAPI() {

console.log(‘Welcome! Fetching your information…. ‘);

FB.api(‘/me’, function(response) {

console.log(‘Successful login for: ‘ + response.name);

document.getElementById(‘status’).innerHTML =

‘Thanks for logging in, ‘ + response.name + ‘!';

});

}

</script>

<fb:login-button scope=”public_profile,email” onlogin=”checkLoginState();”>

</fb:login-button>
<div id=”status”>

</div>
</body>

</html>
```

I found the script from a useful tutorial, If you are thinking about editing this answer please see this tutorial [Facebook Login Integration with website](http://www.tutsapp.com/integrate-facebook-login-with-website-using-javascript-sdk-2014.html)

Answer (score 3):

This type of technology (called OpenConnect, if I'm not mistaken, and they are switching to OAuth) is somewhat the same with OpenID.

Google, indeed, uses openID, and I am not really sure of how they work.

For FacebookConnect, you register your app with facebook ( https://developers.facebook.com/apps ) and you will find details about auth https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/ here.

The idea is that you are going to get a authorization code that you send back to facebook and get an access_token which means your user is authed with your website. You can store this in a $_SESSION var I think... There is no need to store anything to DB, but in your particular setup you can use the userID as the unique user identifier.

Answer (score -2):

Before Outh/OpenID we use to ask user on our website to give there username and password for respected site like facebook , google . Then using Curl we fetch the data from these social sites on behalf of our user . Then this data becomes the source of our Registration form data .Like asking for his name , email , gender in registration form can be skip-ed .

Since user might fear giving there username and password to every site hence there comes a need of Outh . Now we simply redirect the user to facebook , facebook asks for user password . And redirects the user back to our site with auth token appended on url . Which we can get access through $_GET . Using this token we can query facebook for everthing related to that user and hence can skip registration form once again. This data gets stored in table which was meant for Registration Form fields storage .

(This is just an overview there are other steps as-well to take care off )